# Filter records from current Day only in nodejs mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to filter all recoreds that are with the same date from my filter `dateCreated`

I have currently this function but the time and seconds are not what i need.

```
let currentDate = new Date().toISOString()

let users = await User.find({ 
    "dateCreated" : currentDate
}).limit(sanitizedLimit).sort({$natural:-1})

return { users }
```

I want a date e.x 2022-07-10 to filter, regardless of time.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the documents created on a certain date, you would be basically querying everything created from the start of that day, to the end of that day. I'd suggest using a library like moment.js to get the start of day and end of day time. It would be something like this:

```js
let moment = require('moment')
let users = await User.find({ 
    "dateCreated" : {
    $gte: moment().startOf('day').toDate(),
    $lte: moment().endOf('day').toDate()
  }
}).limit(sanitizedLimit).sort({$natural:-1})
```

The gte(greater than or equal to) and lte(less than or equal to) functions work fine in this scenario.